# can i store a value returned by apex method in a javascript variable?

Tags: salesforce

Is it possible to store a value returned by a controller method into a javascript variable?

i need to pass a date and sales qty from salesforce into flot library javascript to build a graph. So what i am doing is formatting a string in apex with the date and salesqty as required by flot library and returning it  in the method.

Can i say in my javascript

```
var d={!getformatteddata};
```

Thanks

Prady

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, just omit the leading 'get':

```
var d='{!formatteddata}';
```

Comment: If its a string, you'll need to quote the value, var d= '{!formatteddata}'

Comment: Yep - that's likely the most common case - updated my answer - thanks! :-)

Comment: when i alert d i get {!formatteddata} as the value rather than the returned value.. any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Can you post a bigger chunk of your code? What's the signature of your controller function?

Comment: Thanks metadaddy, there was an extra leading space in formatteddata which caused the problem..